# Can I use my ubuntu box as a wifi bridge/extender?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have a ubuntu (actually mythbuntu) box that has a wifi card that's capable of acting as an access point. The box itself is connected via ethernet.

I currently have a wifi network through my fios gateway router and I also have an extender. When my mythbuntu backend is running i'd like to have it setup as an extender to increase the range of that area.

Is it possible to set up my wifi card to use the same SSID as my main wifi network and either act as a repeater or a bridge over ethernet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Instructions - http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu-16-04-android-supported/

You can also use the package WiFi Hostapd AP - https://mintguide.org/tools/260-wifi-hostapd-ap-a-simple-application-to-create-wifi-hotspot-on-linux-mint.html

http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/wifi_ap

https://code.google.com/archive/p/wifi-hostapd-ap/

russian forum - http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=279749.0

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Those instructions are for creating a seperate wifi hotspot. I just want to make an extender that uses the same SSID ss my current wifi network.

Comment: What's the difference? I also just made an extender. The network name is the same.